# Resize UIView and change subview position simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiview, uibutton

I have placed out a UIView with a UIButton as a subview in a ViewController in Interface Builder. I also have a UITextField where I have a action witch is triggered every time I type something in it. When I type something my view is supposed to get higher and the button should move to the bottom of the view. But when I type the first letter in the textfield the view resizes but the button doesn't move. When I type a second letter the button moves. Probably because the view is already resized. My question is how to get this to work simultaneously when typing the first letter in the textfield.

My code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyPressed:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];

- (void)keyPressed:(NSNotification*)notification{

    view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 200.0);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, (view.frame.size.height-button.frame.size.height), button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting the button at the bottom of the view. Then when I resized the view the button followed along by staying at the bottom. I didn't need to programmatically move the button.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
 // put your action here 
}
```

Comment: Won't work in my case. I need to know when I type something so that I can return that value. Also this is a shorted down version of my code. In reality the UIViews height is changing depending on what I type in the textfield.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the UIButton is a subview of the UIView as well. Edited the question.

Comment: @DanielTovesson did u still have the problem ??